# C# GUI Dice Game pass by reference

Tags: c#, user-interface, dice

Ok I'm trying to make a GUI dice game where the dice numbers are represented in textboxes.

I have to create a class that represents the dice and at least one of my methods has to correctly pass parameters by reference. My problem is that I am not too experienced with classes or passing parameters

I get an error at 
 rd.RollDice1(ref dice1);
 rd.RollDice2(ref dice2);
(I am sure I have not constructed the RollDice class incorrectly)
Please is there anyone that can help me?

here is my code so far:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private RollDice rd;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        rd = new RollDice();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        int dice1, dice2;

        const int EYE = 1;

         const int BOX = 6;

        rd.RollDice1(ref dice1);

        rd.RollDice2(ref dice2);

        string result = string.Format("{0}", dice1);
        string result2 = string.Format("(0)", dice2);

             textBox1.Text = result;

               textBox2.Text = result;

         if (dice1 == EYE && dice2 == BOX)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("You rolled a Snake Eyes!");

         }
        if (dice1 == BOX && dice2 == BOX)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("You rolled BoxCars!");

        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You rolled a {0} and a {1}", dice1, dice2);
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
class RollDice
{

   const int EYE = 1;
   const int BOX = 6;

    public int RollDice1(ref int dieValue1)
    {
        Random randomNums = new Random();

         dieValue1 = randomNums.Next(1, 7);

        return dieValue1;

    }

    public int RollDice2(ref int dieValue2)
    {
        Random randomNums = new Random();

         dieValue2 = randomNums.Next(1, 7);

        return dieValue2;

    }






}
```

}

Comment: `"I get an error at..."` - And the error is?  Also, why are you passing by reference *and* returning the value?  Might as well just pick one of the two approaches.

Comment: Ah that is why...I'll get red of the returns and continue working on it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Passing a variable with ref requires that variable to be initialized with a default value. If you don't set the two dices with an initial value your compiler complains about `"Use of unassigned local variable xxxxx"`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  

    const int EYE = 1;
    const int BOX = 6;

    int dice1 = EYE;
    int dice2 = BOX;

    rd.RollDice1(ref dice1);
    rd.RollDice2(ref dice2);

    .....
```

However looking at your code there is no need to pass that values using ref, you could simply get the return value

```
    dice1 = rd.RollDice1();
    dice2 = rd.RollDice2();
```

of course you should change the two methods in your class to remove the parameter passed by ref

```
class RollDice
{
    Random randomNums = new Random();

    public int RollDice1()
    {
        return randomNums.Next(1, 7);
    }

    public int RollDice2()
    {
        return randomNums.Next(1, 7);
    }
}
```

Comment: How did I not see that!?!? Haha thank you this is perfect!